# Add a checkbox in product line of orders in prestashop 1.6 backoffice

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop-1.6

I want to add a checkbox in product line of orders in prestashop 1.6 backoffice so that admin can check the checkbox and this value should be stored in the new column in order details table. Someone please guide on this?

Comment: I share with you a post I wrote on how to add a field to products. This is the same update for OrderDetail. It's in French, but code is universal! http://www.paulineghiazza.fr/ajouter-un-champ-dans-le-backoffice-prestashop-1-5/

Comment: @Pauloscorps But I want to edit the order lines in prestashop backoffice not in front office.